# Count hourly data from log file

Tags: linux, shell

I want to get the record count in every hour from log file.
here is the sample data;

```
001:2017-05-23 00:00:01 002:10.10.10.63
001:2017-05-23 00:00:03 002:10.10.10.63
001:2017-05-23 00:00:05 002:10.10.10.63
001:2017-05-23 00:00:07 002:10.10.10.63
001:2017-05-23 00:00:09 002:10.10.10.63
001:2017-05-23 01:00:12 002:10.10.10.63
001:2017-05-23 01:00:14 002:10.10.10.63
```

from above data output should be;

```
00 = 5
01 = 2
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
cut -f2 -d' ' logfile
| cut -f1 -d:
| sort
| uniq -c
| sed 's/ *\([0-9]\+\) \([0-9][0-9]\)/\2 = \1/'
| sort
```

1. only outputs the time.
2. only extracts the hours.
3. sort the output  - needed by the following line
4. counts occurrences of each hour, outputs `count hour`
5. fixes the formatting
6. sorts by hours

Answer (score 0):

You can use `find` with `-printf` attribute as below, I used this in my daily operation:

```
find /path/ -type f -printf '%TY-%Tm-%Td-%TH\n' | sort | uniq -c
```

Answer (score 0):

There are plenty of solutions, one of that is

```
log_file=/var/log/messages                        # log file for extract
d=2022-10-28                                      # start date
while [ "$d" != 2022-11-04 ]; do                  # loop for date range
  echo $d                                         # echo ACTUAL date
  for h in {00..24}; do                           # loop for hours
    act=$(date -d "$d" +'%b %d')" $h:"            # create date for ACTUAL date in requested format: %b return month in Jan Feb..., %d return month number
    echo $act                                     # Print actual hour
    grep "^$act" $log_file                        # grep $ACT from beginning of line of log_file and count lines
  done
  d=$(date -I -d "$d + 1 day")                    # add +1 day for start date to the main loop
done
```